# Slow gif animation with SwiftGif

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, gif, animated-gif

i use this [SwiftGif](https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif) library. I put some gif into UIImageView. This is my code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    self.img1.image=UIImage.gifWithURL("http://mywebsite/img1.gif")
    self.img2.image=UIImage.gifWithURL("http://mywebsite/img2.gif")
    self.img3.image=UIImage.gifWithURL("http://mywebsite/img1.gif")
})
```

The gifs are shown correctly but the animation is slow. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? Having the same issue

Comment: @riverhawk yes, now I use UIWebView instead of SwiftGif library.

Answer (score 8):

Paste the following code in `UIImage+Gif.swift` where calculation of duration  is done in in `animatedImageWithSource` function:

```
 // Calculate full duration
let duration: Int = {
    var sum:Double = 0

    for val: Int in delays {
        let newVal =    Double(val) - (Double(val)/1.5)//Modified calculation to speed up the animtion in gif
        //sum += val :default calculation
        sum += newVal
    }

    return Int(sum)
    }()
```

Answer (score 2):

if your gif size is too big then Use a **webview** to load gif

Add a WebView,

Add gif file to your project directory then add this following code :

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "your-gif-name", withExtension: "gif")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
webView.load(data, mimeType: "image/gif", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: NSURL() as URL)
```

Note: Make your gif file's **height** and **width** as same as the **webview** using any gif editing website

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your gif file size is too big? or the time is too long? because SwiftGif is base on UIAnimatedImage.

And also control your gif frame of 9, 10, 20, 30, 40, and setup GCD to 1.